# What is the action of a primitive permutation group of type SD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

My goal is to show that $Alt(5) \wr Sym(3)$ is a primitive permutation group of type SD.

> Let $G$ be a primitive permutation group, $N$ a minimal normal subgroup, and $H$ a point stabilizer (so $NH = G$). $G$ is of type SD if
>
> 1. $N$ is non-abelian and the unique minimal normal subgroup (so $N \cong T^k$, where $T$ is a non-abelian simple group)
> 2. $N \cap H$ is the diagonal subgroup $\{(t, t, ..., t): t \in T\}$

It follows (as claimed [here](https://symomega.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/the-onan-scott-theorem/)) that $N$ acts on the cosets of $N \cap H$ in $N$, where $(t_1, ..., t_k)$ takes the coset of $(s_1, ..., s_k)$ to the coset of $(t_k^{-1}s_1t_1, ..., 1)$, so we identify $\Omega$ (the underlying set) with $T^{k-1}$. And we identify $G$ with a subgroup of $Aut(T^k) \cong Aut(T) \wr Sym(k)$.

In the case $N = Alt(5)^3$, $G =Alt(5) \wr Sym(3)$ is in the form I want. The only thing I am struggling to understand is the action of this group.

> 1. Is the action of $NH$ on the cosets of $H$ isomorphic to the action of $N$ on the cosets of $N \cap H$?
> 2. If the underlying set $\Omega$ is isomorphic to $Alt(5)^2$, how can I explicitly describe the action of $Alt(5) \wr Sym(3)$?

I am not sure how to answer the $2$nd question without assuming the first. For the first question, (since we do not assume $H$ is normal), I defined a natural bijection between $NH/H$ and $N / N \cap H$, but I could not show that this bijection respects the action.